# GTK+ Warning: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I am trying to write the interface for my music manager using GTK+. The program was compiled successfully. However, when I executed it, the machine returned errors:

```
(dingo_draft:6462): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent


(dingo_draft:6462): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_realize: assertion `GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gtk/gtkwidget.c:8760:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))
Aborted
```

Here is the source code of the program. Please note that this is **just the interface written in GTK+**. I did not add any signals in yet. I think there might be some problems with the GTK+ functions, but I could not locate where the errors occured:

```
/* This is the interface design draft for the media player
/* This does not include the signals for widgets. Just a plain draft */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* Initialize gtk+ & gstreamer */
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  /* Create mainwindow (mainwindow) */
  GtkWidget *mainwindow;

  mainwindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow), "Music Manager");

  /* Create the vbox containing searchbox & song list (treevbox) */
  GtkWidget *searchbox, *treesong, *scrollsong, *treevbox;
  /* GtkWidget *colname, *coltime; */
  GtkCellRenderer *namerender, *timerender;

  treesong = gtk_tree_view_new();
  gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treesong), FALSE);

  namerender = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treesong), -1, "Songs", namerender, "text", 0, NULL);

  timerender = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treesong), -1, "Time", timerender, "text", 1, NULL);

  scrollsong = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrollsong), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrollsong), treesong);

  searchbox = gtk_entry_new();

  treevbox = gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(treevbox), searchbox);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(treevbox), scrollsong);

  /* Create the song info section (infohbox) */
  GtkWidget *songname, *songinfo, *coverart;
  GtkWidget *infohbox, *imagevbox;

  coverart = gtk_image_new_from_file("music-notes.png");
  songname = gtk_label_new("<i>Song Name</i>");
  songinfo = gtk_label_new("<b>Artist:</b> \n <b>Track</b> \n <b>Album</b> \n <b>Year</b> \n <b>Genre</b> \n <b>Rating</b>");

  infohbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  imagevbox = gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(imagevbox), coverart);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(imagevbox), songname);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(infohbox), imagevbox);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(infohbox), songinfo);

  /* Create drawing area for video display (previewarea) */
  GtkWidget *previewarea;

  previewarea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(previewarea, 300, 200);

  /* Create actions tree view (ltreeview) */
  enum {
    COL_ICON = 0,
    COL_ACTION,
    NUM_COLS
  };

  GtkCellRenderer *lrenderer;
  GtkTreeModel *lmodel;
  GtkWidget *ltreeview;
  GtkListStore *lliststore;
  GtkTreeIter liter;

  ltreeview = gtk_tree_view_new();

  lrenderer = gtk_cell_renderer_pixbuf_new();
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(ltreeview), -1, "Icon", lrenderer, "pixbuf", COL_ICON, NULL);

  lrenderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes(GTK_TREE_VIEW(ltreeview), -1, "Actions", lrenderer, "text", COL_ACTION, NULL);

  lliststore = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLS, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF, G_TYPE_STRING);

  gtk_list_store_append(lliststore, &liter);
  gtk_list_store_set(lliststore, &liter, COL_ICON, gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("now-playing.png", NULL), COL_ACTION, "Now Playing", -1);

  gtk_list_store_append(lliststore, &liter);
  gtk_list_store_set(lliststore, &liter, COL_ICON, gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("music.png", NULL), COL_ACTION, "Music", -1);

  gtk_list_store_append(lliststore, &liter);
  gtk_list_store_set(lliststore, &liter, COL_ICON, gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("video.png", NULL), COL_ACTION, "Videos", -1);

  gtk_list_store_append(lliststore, &liter);
  gtk_list_store_set(lliststore, &liter, COL_ICON, gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("playlist.png", NULL), COL_ACTION, "Playlists", -1);

  lmodel = GTK_TREE_MODEL(lliststore);

  gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(ltreeview), lmodel);

  /* g_object_unref(lmodel); */

  /* Create the top control bar (controlhbox) */
  GtkWidget *prevbutton, *nextbutton, *hscale, *cursong;
  GtkWidget *curpos, *duration, *volumebutton, *playbutton;
  GtkAdjustment *progress, *volumeadj;
  GtkWidget *buttonhbox, *proghbox, *infovbox, *controlhbox;

  prevbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(prevbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR));

  playbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(playbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY, GTK_ICON_SIZE_DND));

  nextbutton = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(nextbutton), gtk_image_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY, GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR));

  progress = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00));
  hscale = gtk_hscale_new(progress);
  gtk_scale_set_draw_value(GTK_SCALE(hscale), FALSE);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(hscale, 500, NULL);

  cursong = gtk_label_new("Song's Name");
  curpos = gtk_label_new("0:00");
  duration = gtk_label_new("0:00");

  volumebutton = gtk_volume_button_new();
  volumeadj = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0.70, 0.00, 1.00, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00));
  gtk_scale_button_set_adjustment(GTK_SCALE_BUTTON(volumebutton), volumeadj);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(volumebutton, 32, 32);

  buttonhbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(buttonhbox), prevbutton);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(buttonhbox), playbutton);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(buttonhbox), nextbutton);

  proghbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(proghbox), curpos);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(proghbox), hscale);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(proghbox), duration);

  controlhbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(controlhbox), buttonhbox);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(controlhbox), proghbox);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(controlhbox), volumebutton);

  /* Create panes (tophpaned) and pack widgets into this (tophpaned)*/
  GtkWidget *tophpaned, *subhpaned, *vpaned;

  vpaned = gtk_vpaned_new();
  gtk_paned_add1(GTK_PANED(vpaned), songinfo);
  gtk_paned_add2(GTK_PANED(vpaned), previewarea);

  subhpaned = gtk_hpaned_new();
  gtk_paned_pack1(GTK_PANED(subhpaned), vpaned, TRUE, TRUE);
  gtk_paned_pack2(GTK_PANED(subhpaned), treevbox, TRUE, TRUE);

  tophpaned = gtk_hpaned_new();
  gtk_paned_pack1(GTK_PANED(tophpaned), ltreeview, TRUE, TRUE);
  gtk_paned_pack2(GTK_PANED(tophpaned), subhpaned, TRUE, TRUE);

  /* Create an topvbox to pack all the above stuffs in, */
  /* then add topvbox to window */
  GtkWidget *topvbox;

  topvbox = gtk_vbox_new(TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(topvbox), controlhbox);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(topvbox), tophpaned);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwindow), topvbox);

  /* Show all widgets & draw the interface */ 
  gtk_widget_show_all(mainwindow);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you for answering my question! I appreciate your helps!

Comment: Is `scrollsong` initialized before a `treesong` is added into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to put `songinfo` into two different containers: into `infohbox` and into `vpaned`.

As Havoc says, gdb can help you find the exact code that is giving you a warning. I can offer two additional suggestions:

- Build your interface in Glade. This will help you to see what's going on with it as you build it. It will also make it more maintainable, and help you avoid these kinds of errors.
- Before you ask a question on Stack Overflow with a big code dump, try and make a minimal program that reproduces the problem. Often you will have solved the problem yourself by the time you have done this.

Answer (score 4):

Run in a debugger (gdb), set a breakpoint on the *first* warning message (used to be g_logv that all warnings went through, but check glib
source if needed), then type "bt" in gdb when it breaks to see which line caused the warning.

Another approach is to set `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` in the environment, then again use gdb, no need for a breakpoint just backtrace when the app crashes on the warning.

Another possible step is to run in Valgrind and fix its complaints if you have bad memory accesses or writes.